# SQL statement to connect 5 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Ok, so i want to populate a gridview with a rather complex statement that i have no idea how to get, I dont even know if its possible. five tables and a view are involved, these arent all the fields in the tables but just to make things clearer, i only put the required fields.

Student Table:-

```
Student_ID
Specialization_ID
```

Specialization Table:-

```
ID
Specialization_Name
Department_ID
```

Staff Table:-

```
ID
Staff_ID 
Department_ID
```

Department Table:-

```
ID
Department_Name
```

Survey Table:- (`Username` is the uploader)

```
ID
Username
```

Users View:- (Here the `Username`, `Password` is taken from both the student table and the staff table)

```
Username
Password
UserType
```

This is how i created the view:-

```
CREATE View [Users] as
Select Student_ID as Username, Password,'STU' as UserType from Student
union
Select Staff_ID, Password, 'STF' as UserType from Staff
```

Now, considering that when a staff member signs in, his username is stored in session `Session["Username"]`, what i want to pull from the database, are all the surveys that are uploaded by users (only students) that have a specialization that belongs to the current user's department. considering that all relationships (foreign keys) are set, what is the sql query i should use? or the method at least.

Comment: I can't find the relation between the first 4 tables and the last two. How do you relate a UserName to the students?

Comment: What does "his username is stored in session `Session["Username"]` mean?  What is `Session["Username"]`?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Iam storing the current logged in user's login ID in session, using the session function is asp.net c#.

Comment: @Steve I edited my question to show you how i created the view.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** First try to figure out the connections between your tables (FK and PK - for a start point, it looks like Specialization, Staff and Department tables do have relation).

Then come up with the query that works. Try to convert that to a view and depending on number of records measure the performance.

Although it is a guideline how to proceed, i am pretty sure that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i solved it using subqueries after a an hour of grinding ...Thanks all for the help.

```
    Select * From Survey where Username IN 
(Select Student_ID from Student where Specialization_ID IN 
(Select ID from Specialization where Department_ID = 
(Select Department_ID from Staff where Staff_ID =@Username)))
```

Comment: You should look at `JOIN` instead of `subquery` (as suggested by "ElYusubov". `subquery` is probably the worst option you could take here.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why there isn't another table between the user and the staff?

It could possibe be called UserStaffTable which would have the two id columns as a composite key, and two extra columns referencing the specialization and departmenttable? This way you always have a list of students that belong to a staff member, and you could filter them out based on specializations, and/or departments.

This will allow you to perform a join rather than a subquery.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-subquery) subqueries are slower, if this at all matters.